# A hidden <td> with colspan set does not work after unhiding it with JS

Tags: javascript, html-table

I can't get a hidden `<td>` with a `colspan` set at 2 to work after it has been unhidden with JS.

As can be seen in the example, I am trying to hide 2 td-elements and unhide another with the colspan set at 2

I use the following code to hide and unhide the elements:

```
function unhideColspan() {
document.getElementById("aa").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("bb").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("cc").style.display = 'block';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eecvx8or/3/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("cc").style.display = 'block';
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("cc").style.display = 'table-cell';
```

Snippet:

```js
function unhideColspan() {
document.getElementById("aa").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("bb").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("cc").style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
}
.a {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
table {
    width: 610px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
```

```html
<div>WITH COLSPAN APPLIED</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a"><div></div></td>
        <td class="a" colspan="2"><div></div></td>
        <td class="a"><div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</br>
</br>
<div>WITHOUT COLSPAN</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a"><div></div></td>
        <td class="a"><div></div></td>
        <td class="a"><div></div></td>
        <td class="a">
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</br>
</br>
<div>UNHIDE COLSPAN WITH JS</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="aa" class="a"><div>aa</div></td>
        <td id="bb" class="a"><div>bb</div></td>
        <td id="cc" class="a" colspan="2" style="display: none;"><div>cc</div></td>
        <td id="dd" class="a"><div>dd</div></td>
        <td id="ee" class="a"><div>ee</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</br>
<button onclick="unhideColspan()">OK</button>
```

Comment: I can not accept the answer within 10 minutes. Will do it in a couple of minutes